# (GWT leaflet) layer returns "null" of "_leaflet_id" property

Tags: java, gwt, leaflet

I have the grid with my class Geofence. Separately I use leaflet to create layers aka geofence.
When I get geofence from the server I filling the grid and creating and adding layers to FeatureGroup drawnItems. I set up the property of a layer as geofence's id.
Here is the code:

```
if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
   JsArray<Geofence> geofenceJsArray = JsonUtils.safeEval(response.getText());
ILayer iLayer;
   for (int i = 0; i < geofenceJsArray.length(); i++) {
       geofenceStore.add(geofenceJsArray.get(i));
       JsArray<Coordinate> coordinateJsArray = geofenceJsArray.get(i).getCoordinates();
       if (geofenceJsArray.get(i).getType() == Type.CIRCLE) {
         double lat = coordinateJsArray.get(0).getLatitude();
         double lon = coordinateJsArray.get(0).getLongitude();
         LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
         double radius = geofenceJsArray.get(i).getRadius();
         Options options = new Options();
         iLayer = new Circle(latLng, radius, options);
         iLayer.getJSObject().setProperty("_leaflet_id", geofenceJsArray.get(i).getId());
      } else {
         PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
         LatLng[] latLngArray = new LatLng[coordinateJsArray.length()];
         for (int j = 0; j < coordinateJsArray.length(); j++) {
           double lat = coordinateJsArray.get(i).getLatitude();
           double lon = coordinateJsArray.get(i).getLongitude();
           latLngArray[j] = new LatLng(lat, lon);
         }
         iLayer = new Polygon(latLngArray, polylineOptions);
         iLayer.getJSObject().setProperty("_leaflet_id", geofenceJsArray.get(i).getId());
      }
      drawnItems.addLayer(iLayer);
      map.addLayer(iLayer);
 }
```

But when I want to remove some geofence like this:
[image]

using this code:

```
if (204 == response.getStatusCode()) {
  ILayer layerForRemove = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < drawnItems.getLayers().length; i++) {
    LoggerHelper.log(className, "_leaflet_id: " + drawnItems.getLayers()[i].getOptions().getProperty("_leaflet_id") + "");
    if (selectedGeofence.getId() == Integer.parseInt(drawnItems.getLayers()[i].getOptions().getProperty("_leaflet_id") + "")) {
      layerForRemove = drawnItems.getLayers()[i];
    }
  }
  drawnItems.removeLayer(layerForRemove);
  geofenceStore.remove(selectedGeofence);
  Info.display("Уведомление", "Геозона " + selectedGeofence.getName() + " успешно удалено!");
  LoggerHelper.log(className, "Device " + selectedGeofence.getName() + " has been removed. Bye-bye!");
} else {
    Info.display("Ошибка", "Не удалось удалить геозону  " + selectedGeofence.getName());
    LoggerHelper.log(className, "Error while deleting device. " +
                                        "Error code: " + response.getStatusCode() +
                                        ". Error status message: " + response.getStatusText());
}
```

I receiving _leaflet_id as "null" in this line

```
LoggerHelper.log(className, "_leaflet_id: " + drawnItems.getLayers()[i].getOptions().getProperty("_leaflet_id") + "");
```

Why? Because I set up it in this line:

```
iLayer.getJSObject().setProperty("_leaflet_id", geofenceJsArray.get(i).getId());
```

Thanks in advance for answer!

Comment: By seeing, first call (200 == response.getStatusCode()) and second call (204 == response.getStatusCode()), I can see they are two different calls, Could you ensure the first call is always executed first and the object is populated? Also the iLayer (//added in drawnItems.addLayer(iLayer)), should not be removed before the second call is invoked.

Comment: Status code 200 I receive when making GET request and 204 when making DELETE request. Also, I removing iLayer if DELETE request shows 204 status code

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't handle the `_leaflet_id` **private** property of Leaflet layers at all. Trying to do so will create unexpected problems.

You are free to add custom properties to Leaflet layers, and keep references to them, e.g.:

```
var geofencesById = {}

for (...) {
    layer = L.polygon(...);

    layer._geofence_id = geofenceJsArray.get(i).getId();
    geofencesById[ geofenceJsArray.get(i).getId() ] = layer;
}
```

Comment: You mean I may do this in leaflet library?

Comment: I mean you do not touch `_leaflet_id` unless you're coding leaflet or a low-level leaflet plugin.

Comment: Ok, so, how I can match my geofence object with the layer? I don't understand properly your code above.